# Hyperledger Fabric - Offline peer prevents organization from connecting to the network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have a test environment for hyperledger fabric 2.2. Two organizations with 2 peers, each.

I wanted to simulate an offline peer, so I shut down `peer2-org1` for testing purposes, which results in a broken application for org1.

This is the node application code, which is basically taken from the example:

```
        this.gateway = new Gateway();
        const gatewayOpts = {
            wallet: this.wallet,
            identity: username,
            discovery: {
                enabled: true,
                asLocalhost: false
            }
        } as GatewayOptions;

        await this.gateway.connect(this.config, gatewayOpts);
        this.network = await this.gateway.getNetwork('somechannel');
```

The last command `gateway.getNetwork` throws the following exception:

```
Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Discoverer- name: peer2-org1, url:grpcs://peer2-org1:7051, connected:false, connectAttempted:true
     at checkState (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:69:26)
     at Timeout._onTimeout (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/channel.js:292:17)
     at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
     at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7) {
   connectFailed: true
}
```

I found out, that the application will work if I remove the offline peer `peer2-org1` from the `gateway.connect` configuration object, which looks like this:

```
(...)
"organizations": {
        "org1": {
            "mspid": "org1",
            "peers": [
                "peer1-org1", "peer2-org1"
            ],
            "certificateAuthorities": [
                "rca-org1"
            ]
        }
    },
(...)
```

How can I make this work and tell the library to continue with peer1 if peer2 is not available?

Comment: Are your peers running in docker on your local system, or are they on separate servers?

Comment: It's a local docker-compose environment. But the node-application is also running inside the docker environment (that's why asLocalhost is false).